# NullPointerException, but only when I connect my Android phone to computer

Tags: java, android-studio, error-handling, exception, nullpointerexception

I'm making Android applications using Android Studio. When I connect my phone to my computer to test my applications, I get this error. And it comes like an endless loop.
I thought that my app caused this error, but I tested and I realized that it happens when I connect my phone to laptop. I **don't** get this error when I use an emulator. How can I fix this ? And is this a big problem?

I tried this with several projects and the result is the same. And as far as i understand it only occurs when I connect my phone. I mean no need to run a project. I connect the phone and it occurs.

Error:

```
E/ParseCommandCache: saveEventually thread had an error.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
    at com.parse.ParseCommand$6.call(ParseCommand.java:438)
    at com.parse.ParseCommand$6.call(ParseCommand.java:1)
    at com.parse.Task$3.run(Task.java:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Looks like, at some point, a JSON data structure is passed. And in this particular situation, that structure is `null`. Or it doesn't have a node where one is expected. It might help if you include the code where this occurs. But since it only happens when running on the physical device, it may be a configuration issue.

Comment: Are you using firebase sdk or the Parse SDK directly? Maybe another app on your device does it. However, this message seems to be caused by a line of [some code in the Parse SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/master/parse/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseCommandCache.java).

Comment: @S.L.Barth I tried this with several projects and result is same. And as far as i understand it only occurs when I connect my phone. I mean no need to run a project. I connect the phone and it occurs.

Comment: @deHaar Yes i use firebase. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I've edited the information into your question. I don't know the answer myself, but hopefully someone else will. If you disagree with my edit, you can revert it - there is a menu under the "edited ... ago"  link. Or you can further edit it with more information. Good luck, hope you'll get an answer!

Comment: @S.L.Barth I understand. Thank you for edit, it looks better.